# MySQL stored procedure to turn inventory movement into inventories

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Let's start with this table:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `resourceMovement` (
  `resourceID` INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `movementDateTime` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  `movementQuantity` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `fromLocationID` INT(4) UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `fromIndividualID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `fromDeptID` INT(4) UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `toLocationID` INT(4) UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `toIndividualID` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `toDeptID` INT(4) UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `lastUpdated` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`resourceID`, `movementDateTime`, `movementQuantity`) ,
  [ List of foreign key constraints. ]
```

This tracks over time how a particular amount of a particular resourceID gets moved from one department/location/person to another department/location/person.

What I would like to do is create a ... something. A procedure or a trigger or a view that loops over the toLocationID/toIndividualID/toDeptID values and generates running inventories for each resourceID associated with those destinations.

I'm not even remotely good enough at MySQL stored procedures to do this efficiently.

I suppose I could create three running inventory tables, one each for departments, locations, and persons, and have a trigger to update those tables as the movement table gets updated. Would regular tables or temporary tables be better for that?

And the detail questions just keep coming. So, I'll just leave the general question: what's the best way to scan a table that audits inventory movement in order to determine actual running inventories?

Thanks!

Comment: You could have departments, locations, persons tables and one inventory table for all of them.. :)

Comment: I could. Creating the tables isn't the hard part. Creating the trigger or stored procedure is the hard part... :-) I could do this in PHP, but keeping these updates in MySQL seems faster.

Comment: You don't want to use temporary tables for this; they're only visible to the owning connection, and are deleted when that connection is closed, whereas this data could be shared by a series of connections.

Comment: What is the relationship between locations, individuals, and departments?

Comment: No relationship is required. An individual turning in a piece of audited equipment would generate a record fromIndividualID -> toLocationID. A transfer from Central Stores to a particular group could contain the toDeptGroupID of the given group, the toLocationID of where they're keeping the inventory, ~and~ the toIndividualID of the person checking out the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented systems similar to this in the past. It seems to work the best(for me) to  break this up into a few tables.

> **resource**
>   - resource id
>   - resource description
>   - quantity
>
> **changes**
>   - change id
>   - change date/time stamp
>   - change type
>   - resource id
>   - destination id
>   - quantity
>
> **destination**
>   - destination id
>   - destination type

Change types would include:
- new stock from distributor
- assign some portion to a person/place/event
- discard stock
- warranty replacement
- sales

Destination would include:
- person / place / event - (in your case it would be dept, person and location)

To find out how much (*total*) you have in stock:

> select from resource

To find out how much a given *destination* has:

> select from resource join changes join destination where stamp <= interesting event

To find the *history* of a given item:

> select from changes where resource =

So you don't have to run ongoing updates.. you just have to track changes.. and it happens in a (reasonably) normalized fashion.